# Calculate how much positions of 2 arrays contain equal elements

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, enumerable

I have 2 `arrays` of the same length and I need to calculate how much of their positions contains equal elements. I made this function but I feel it could be done without creating a `tuple`. Is there a more vast and easy way to do this?

```
static int GetCoincidence(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    return a.Zip(b, Tuple.Create).Where(x => x.Item1 == x.Item2).Select(x => 1).Sum();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicates between arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247744/find-duplicates-between-arrays)

Comment: `.Where(x => x.Item1 == x.Item2).Select(x => 1).Sum()` is equivalent to `.Count(x => x.Item1 == x.Item2)`. You're being more verbose than you need to be. But your version is not wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
static int GetCoincidence(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    return a.Where((x,i)=>x==b[i]).Count();
}
```

Try this [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zrm8Ho) usage :

```
int[] a= {1,2,3,4,55,6,77,7,8,9};
int[] b= {1,2,3,4,34,5,79,7,8,9};
Console.WriteLine(GetCoincidence(a,b));
// Output will be 7
```

Comment: You can condense the `.Where((x,i)=>x==b[i]).Count()` to `.Count((x,i)=>x==b[i])`. Minor detail, but people seem to often forget that a Count already includes the functionality of a Where :)

Comment: @Flater: No it is not possible since `Count()` doesn't support the second argument `i`, Can you make a try and let me know if I'm wrong?

Comment: You're right; Count does not have the second argument possible. That seems counterintuitive since both Select and Where do have the option. But regardless, you're right.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative without `Tuple` (I've tried to *preserve* your idea with `Sum`):

```
  int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 9};
  int[] b = new int[] { 7, 8, 3, 4, 4, 8};

  int count = a
    .Zip(b, (left, right) => left == right ? 1 : 0)
    .Sum();
```

Comment: This is better than currently accepted answer (no closure introduced) and the original (no tuple allocation). The sad thing with LINQ is that people tend to choose the answers that *look* concise using randomly chosen variable names like `x`, `y`, `z`, `zz` etc and putting everything in a single line. I'm pretty sure if you just  copy/pasted the function definition like other answers and wrote inside `return a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x == y ? 1 : 0).Sum();` would get more likes (and even accept :)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, your solution is reasonably elegant, due to the use of `Zip()` to create the parallel enumeration needed. The alternative is to manage the `IEnumerator<T>` objects yourself explicitly, which isn't pretty.

The one change I'd make is use `Count()` instead of `Where()`, `Select()` and `Sum()`:

```
static int GetCoincidence(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    return a.Zip(b, Tuple.Create).Count(x => x.Item1 == x.Item2);
}
```

Note that with this approach, you can accomplish the goal with any `IEnumerable<T>` implementation, not just arrays. If you are satisfied with using *only* arrays, you can use the `Where()` overload that provides an index, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44151298).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) Except for this.
Here is example how you can do it:

```
public static int GetCoincidence(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    return a.Count()-a.Except(b).Count();
}
```

Comment: This will not take into account the **order** of the elements in the sequences, as the OP appears to want.

Comment: @PeterDuniho oh, yes , you are right I have not noticed that in question

Answer (score 0):

```
var common = (from elemA in a.Select((x, y) => new { Value = x, Index = y })
                     join elemB in b.Select((x, y) => new { Value = x, Index = y })
                     on new { elemA.Index, elemA.Value } equals new { elemB.Index, elemB.Value }
                     select elemA).ToList();
```